# RxSwift tutorial example: Attribute can only be applied to types, not declarations

Tags: ios, iphone, rx-swift

I am trying to go through the `RxSwift` tutorial here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/138547/getting-started-with-rxswift-and-rxcocoa

After downloading their example code, and doing `pod install` successfully, the build is still failing. It is showing the error in the `Lock.swift` file and is shown below:

[image]

What should I do to eliminate the error and make it to run? It is disappointing that the tutorial is not up to date. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the error will be gone after removing the `@noescape`attribute, it's not the correct way to fix the error. Manually editing the pod files are not recommended.

To fix this error, open the terminal and heading to the project folder. Simply type `pod update`. After updating the pods, all the errors will be gone.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `@noescape` will fix the error. `@noescape` is default

```
func performLocked(action: () -> Void)
```